# EarthEngine save TIFF - Python API Changes?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

This code used to work using the Python API:

```
    url = ee.data.makeDownloadUrl(ee.data.getDownloadId({
          'image': image.serialize(),
          'scale': '%d' % scale,
          'filePerBand': 'false',
          'name': 'data',
    }))
```

It now complains that

```
   Image as JSON string not supported.
```

I'm assuming something changed in the API but I can't figure out what I need to change the "example" in the documenation is empty.

Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the low-level `ee.data.makeDownloadUrl` method, it is simpler to use the [ee.Image.getDownloadURL](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl) method.

```python
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

sample_img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA/LT05_031034_20110619')
url = sample_img.getDownloadURL({
  'scale':300,
  'filePerBand':False
})
```

Downloading directly may work for small images, but larger scale downloads should use [batch export tasks](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting), using the [ee.batch](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/batch.py) module of the Python client library.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the .serialize() method:

```
 url = ee.data.makeDownloadUrl(ee.data.getDownloadId({
          'image': image,
          'scale': '%d' % scale,
          'filePerBand': 'false',
          'name': 'data',
    }))
```